# Choosing pivot while solving Linear Programming in case the constraints are lesser than the available variables.

Tags: linear-programming, simplex

I am trying to solve a LP with simplex method which says like.
Suppose,

Maximize $$10x_1+20x_2+20x_3$$

subject to

\begin{align}
\tfrac{2}{3}x_1+4x_2+x_3&\leq 50&& (I)\\[0.5em]
x_1 + 3x_2 + 4x_3 &\leq 130&& (A)\\[0.5em]
x_1, x_2, x_3 &\ge 0&&(B)
\end{align}

How are we supposed to solve this case?

I started by converting it to slack form, after which I have two new variables $s_1$ and $s_2$. I 
converted equations A and B to $s_1$ and $s_2$ form and then put non basic variables ($x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$) to zero to get a feasible solution.

After that, I have taken $x_1$  as pivot and changed it with S1 to optimize my value(which has improved a lot). But, now how will I choose my next pivot as I can only choose one to replace with $s_2$. I don't have a $s_3$ in this case to replace $x_3$.

So, in these cases, how should I proceed further? Should I replace $x_2$ with $s_2$ first and check optimized value of Z, and then repeat for $x_3$ with $s_2$ and then choose the best out of these? Or is there any other way?

Please help. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Anyone, knowing about this??

Answer (score 2):

To solve this with the Simplex Method you have to convert the inequalities of the contraints into equalities using slack variables:

\begin{align}
\tfrac{2}{3}x_1+4x_2+x_3 +s_1&=50&& (I)\\[0.5em]
x_1 + 3x_2 + 4x_3 +s_2&= 130&& (A)\\[0.5em]
x_1, x_2, x_3,s_1,s_2 &\ge 0&&(B)
\end{align}

\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{2}{3} & 4 &1  &  1& 0\\ 
1 & 3 & 4 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}

Now you have to check which columns of the matrix are basic.Since the last two cloumns create the identity matrix, these are the basic columns.

$$b=[50; 130]$$
$$c=[10; 20; 20; 0; 0]$$

The next step is to create the tableau.

Can you continue?